# Fubini - counterexample

Tags: real-analysis, fubini-tonelli-theorems

On $[0,1]\times [0,\infty)$, consider the function
$$
f(x,y)=(2-xy)xy\exp(-xy).
$$
Why is Fubini's theorem **not** applicable?

I get that $\int_0^\infty\int_0^1 f(x,y)\, dx\, dy =1\neq 0=\int_0^1\int_0^\infty f(x,y)\, dy\, dx$ but **why** is Fubini not applicable?

Comment: Have you checked the Fubini theorem Hypothesis? The function takes negative values...

Comment: @geetha290krm No. But when the function takes only non-negative values there are less hypothesis to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is neither integrable nor non-negative.

Using Tonelli and changing $(x,y)$ to $(t,y)$ where $t=xy$ we get  $\int |f(x,y)|d(x,y)=\int_0^{\infty} \int_t^{\infty}y|2-t||t|e^{-t}dydt=\infty$.

Comment: where do you use tonelli in your argumentation?

Comment: I am computing a  double integral w.r.t. $(t,y)$ by integrating w.r.t. $t$ first and then w.r.t. $y$ @selector

Comment: But your inner integral is over y

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say 'I am computing a double integral w.r.t. (t,y) by integrating w.r.t. $y$ first and then w.r.t. $t$' @selector

Comment: @selector One way to justify the steps is to limit $y$ to $(0,M)$ for some $M$ and apply standard change of variable formula from Calculus. You can let $M \to \infty$ at the end.

Comment: Shouldn't it be
$$
\int_0^\infty\int_t^\infty\frac{1}{y}\vert 2-t\vert t \exp(-t)\, dy\, dt?
$$

Comment: I guess the idea is that you apply Tonelli by saying that: IF the function was integrable w.r.t. the product measure, at least one of the double integrals was integrable (and then also the other). So it suffices to show that ONE of the double integrals is NOT integrable?